# Unable to activate Evernote API key

Tags: evernote

I'm trying to activate my API key with Evernote using the below link:

https://dev.evernote.com/support/

When I click Submit the spinner just goes forever. Dev Tools has one error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500: https://dev.evernote.com/zendesk/zdform.php
```

Any suggestions? Are there any more direct ways to activate my api key?

Comment: Confirmed that Evernote is working to fix it.

Comment: @kentaro thanks. I have now successfully requested activation of my API key. May I ask how you knew Evernote were working on it, for future reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evernote have fixed the form now. Thanks @kentaro for your info